# How to loop multidimensional array from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api, multidimensional-array

After reading muiltiple stackoverflow questions I'm still confused on why I am not able to get this to work. I am attempting to take all of the rows of a mysql table and put them into a multidimensional array. I was hoping to just find a simple example but so far I'm not fully understanding.

The examples I've seen on google and stack is mostly about parsing or making it iterate on the page. I am attempting to have the mysql rows iterate into their arrays. The example code I started working with was similiar to this:

```
// This will hopefully get all of the categories
case 'get_all_categories' :
    $query = '
        SELECT `id`,`category_name`, `category_spam`
        FROM `category`
        ';

    if (!$go = @mysql_query($query)) {
        $results = Array(
                    'head' => Array(
                            'status' => '0',
                            'error_number' => '604', 
                            'error_message' => 'Select Failed. '.
                            'Probably wrong name supplied.'
                        ),
                    'body' => Array ()
                );
    } else {
        $fetch = mysql_fetch_row($go);
        $return = Array($fetch[0],$fetch[1]);  
        $results = Array(  
                    'body' => Array (  
                            'id'    => $return[0],  
                            'category_name' => $return[1]  
                        )  
                ); 
    }
    break;
```

This obviously provides me with the result of just ONE as that is what I'm asking it to do with `fetch_row`.

i.e.

```
//outputs
{"body":{"id":"1","category_name":"Star Wars"}}
```

I've attempted to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and then do a `foreach` loop? 
I"ve also tried doing a `mysql_fetch_all($go)` and then attempt to put the rows into it.

```
if (!$go = @mysql_query($query)) {
    $results = Array(
                'head' => Array(
                        'status' => '0',
                        'error_number' => '604', 
                        'error_message' => 'Select Failed. '.
                        'Probably wrong name supplied.'
                    ),
                'body' => Array ()
            );
} else {
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_row($go)){
        Array(
            'body' => Array(
                    'id' => $myrow[o], 
                    'category_name' => $myrow[1],
                    'category_spam' => $myrow[2]
                )
    }
    );
}
break;
```

I am attempting to make an api call where the body holds all of the categories and their id's (the point I believe is then for the categories to pull and show the lists...which I'm hoping is the right away to make an api(not a question just rambling)

So: how do I make the query take all of the mysql rows and loop them into arrays for the body array. (note: I'm new to API's if my terminology is wrong to what my overall goal is which is to get an api call to show my whole mysql array then please let me know).

**EDIT** Just adding more info from the comments

The output is JSON encoded (sorry I should have explained that)

```
switch ($_GET['format']) {
        case 'xml' :
                @header ("content-type: text/xml charset=utf-8");
                $xml = new XmlWriter();
                $xml->openMemory();
                $xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
                $xml->startElement('callback');
                $xml->writeAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
                $xml->writeAttribute('xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation','schema.xsd');
                function write(XMLWriter $xml, $data){
                        foreach($data as $key => $value){
                                if(is_array($value)){
                                        $xml->startElement($key);
                                        write($xml, $value);
                                        $xml->endElement();
                                        continue;
                                }
                                $xml->writeElement($key, $value);
                        }
                }
                write($xml, $results);

                $xml->endElement();
                echo $xml->outputMemory(true);
            break;
        case 'json' :
                @header ("content-type: text/json charset=utf-8");
                echo json_encode($results);
            break;
        case 'php' :
                header ("content-type: text/php charset=utf-8");  
                echo serialize($results);  
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You normally don't want to suppress errors like `@mysql_query()`, you want to solve them.

Comment: I maybe missing something here but have you tried: $results .= Array(  
'body'.. (Notice the dot before the = sign).

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I'm a newbie but I was under the impression that by having !$go = @mysql_query() that was like saying if go doesn't have any suppressed errors do this.... or am I completely misunderstanding @??

Comment: @jeff I attempted that and it didn't really help. I"m not a 100% sure how .= works either but I attempted it. Additionally The first part of the code works as you can see by my json output. I'm just having a hard time getting all of my table into an array and I haven't seen anyone asking this (or I"m asking this the wrong way?!)

Comment: I'm not sure actually, it really looks overly complicated. I find it much easier to show the errors for development/debug and to log the errors/exceptions for production. From the [documentation](http://es1.php.net/mysql_query) we can see that you don't need the `@`, since it **returns** false on error, it doesn't stop the code. Make sure you use `if (mysql_query !== false)`, with `!==`, as the query might return 0 or "" without them being false. Also, try to update your code to PDO since mysql_* is being **deprecated**

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia changing to PDO is a priority to me, but I am self-taught and to grasp some of the things I don't get I go back to mysql and then try it in PDO....you may be getting another q from me after all :P j/k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $res = mysql_query($query);   
   $results = array();
   $i = 0;
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $results['body'][$i]['id']            =  $row[o];
            $results['body'][$i]['category_name'] =  $row[1];
            $results['body'][$i]['category_spam'] =  $row[2];
            $i++;
   }
   if(empty($results['body'])){
          $results['head'] =  Array(
                            'status' => '0',
                            'error_number' => '604', 
                            'error_message' => 'Select Failed. '.
                            'Probably wrong name supplied.'
                             );
   }

   break;
```

Try the above code it will create $result array for your json response.

Rest everything is fine!

Comment: This displays my last entry.  i.e. {"body":{"id":"5","category_name":"Sports"}} as opposed to {"body":{"id":"1","category_name":"Star Wars"}}         Any thoughts?

Comment: That does exactly what I was hoping for! So what I was missing in my initial while loop was the i/i++ and making an 'array''array' If I was going 3 arrays deep it would be like this ['array1']['array2'][$i]['value'] with $i being the array and rolling out what was in said array?

Comment: exactly you just need to check indexs of array...2D, 3D ...so on